# How to sum a slice from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sum the a portion of the sessions in my dictionary so I can get totals for the current and previous week.

I've converted the JSON into a pandas dataframe in one test. I'm summing the total of the sessions using the .sum() function in pandas. However, I also need to know the total sessions from this week and the week prior. I've tried a few methods to sum values (-1:-7) and (-8:-15), but I'm pretty sure I need to use .iloc.

IN:

```
response = requests.get("url")
data = response.json()
df=pd.DataFrame(data['DailyUsage'])

total_sessions = df['Sessions'].sum()
current_week= df['Sessions'].iloc[-1:-7]
print(current_week) 
total_sessions =['current_week'].sum
```

OUT:

```
Series([], Name: Sessions, dtype: int64)
AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

Note: I've tried this with and without pd.to_numeric and also with variations on the syntax of the slice and sum methods. Pandas doesn't feel very Pythonic and I'm out of ideas as to what to try next.

Comment: Most probably you have a typo in `['current_week'].sum`. Remove the `[' ']`, as for now it reads as "list with one string element"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `df['Sessions']` holds each day, and you are comparing current and previous week only, you can use `reshape` to create a weekly sum for the last 14 values.

```
weekly_matrix = df['Sessions'][:-15:-1].values.reshape((2, 7))
```

Then, you can sum each row and get the weekly sum, most recent will be the first element.

```
import numpy as np    

weekly_sum = np.sum(weekly_matrix, axis=1)
current_week = weekly_sum[0]
previous_week = weekly_sum[1]
```

---

**EDIT:** how the code works

Let's take the 1D-array which is accessed by the [values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) attribute of the pandas Series. It contains the last 14 days, which is ordered from most recent to the oldest. I will call it `x`.

```
x = array([14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

The array's [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) function is then called on `x` to split this data into a 2D-array (matrix) with 2 rows and 7 columns.

The default behavior of the [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) function is to first fill all columns in a row before moving to the next row. Therefore, x[0] will be the element (1,1) in the reshaped array, x[1] will be the element (1,2), and so on. After the element (1,7) is filled with x[6] (ending the current week), the next element x[7] will then be placed in (2,1). This continues until finishing the reshape operation, with the placement of x[13] in (2,7).

This results in placing the first 7 elements of `x` (current week) in the first row, and the last 7 elements of `x` (previous week) in the second row. This was called `weekly_matrix`.

```
weekly_matrix = x.reshape((2, 7))

# weekly_matrix = array([[14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8],
#                        [ 7,  6,  5,  4,  3, 2, 1]])
```

Since now we have the values of each week organized in a matrix, we can use [numpy.sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) function to finish our operation. [numpy.sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) can take an `axis` argument, which will control how the value is computed:

- if `axis=None`, all elements are added in a grand total.
- if `axis=0`, all rows in each column will be added. In the case of `weekly_matrix`, this will result in a 7 element 1D-array ([21, 19,
  17, 15, 13, 11, 9], which is not the result we want, as we are
  actually adding equivalent days on each week).
- if `axis=1` (as the case of the solution), all columns in each row will be added, producing a 2 element 1D-array in the case of `weekly_matrix`. Order of this result
  array follows the same order of the rows in the matrix (i.e., element
  0 is the total of the first row, and element 1 is the total of the
  second row). Since we know that the first row is the current week, and
  the second row is the previous week, we can extract the information
  using these indexes, which is

  ```
  # weekly_sum = array([77, 28])
  current_week = weekly_sum[0]     # sum of [14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8] = 77
  previous_week = weekly_sum[1]    # sum of [ 7,  6,  5,  4,  3, 2, 1] = 28
  ```

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you. Can you explain why weekly_sum[0] and weekly_sum[1] correctly segmented the list?

Comment: Sure. I will edit the solution and post the explanation

Answer (score 0):

To group and sum by a fixed number of values, for instance with daily data and weekly aggregation, consider [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). You can do this forwards *or* backwards by slicing your series as appropriate:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.random.randint(0, 10, 21)})

print(df['col'].values)
# array([5, 0, 3, 3, 7, 9, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 6, 8, 8, 1, 6, 7, 7, 8, 1, 5])

# forwards groupby
res = df['col'].groupby(df.index // 7).sum()
# 0    30
# 1    40
# 2    35
# Name: col, dtype: int32

# backwards groupby
df['col'].iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True).groupby(df.index // 7).sum()
# 0    35
# 1    40
# 2    30
# Name: col, dtype: int32
```